# How can I get a screenshot which contains a playing AVPlayer view? Always get a black view for the AVPlayer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avplayer

My app need to get a screenshot of the current window. But when current screen contains a playing AVPlayer, the AVPlayer view in the screenshot  shows a black view. And it always happens in real device but not the simulator. It is very bad experience.

```
CGContextSaveGState(
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);  
CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);  
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x, -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);  
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)  
{  
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);  
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -imageSize.width);  
}  
else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)  
{  
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI_2);  
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.height, 0);  
} else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {  
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);  
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.width, -imageSize.height);  
}  
if ([window respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)])  
{  
    [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];  
}  
else  
{  
    [window.layer renderInContext:context];  
}  
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```